# setOnClickListener not showing in basic Kotlin application

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm really sorry if this question is at all redundant. I have read several posts and for some reason this issue does not seem to come up for anyone else. As such, I really hope it's solvable.

Long story short, I am a beginner in Android dev and I'm working with Kotlin. When I go to add "onClickListener" to a button, I get an error. The id is set to "button" so presumably I can just write "button.onClickListener {}" and begin my code. But for some reason this gives me and error.

[image: button without method]

As you can see here, I am not getting any methods provided for me off of "button"

The error I am getting is "kotlinx.android.main.activity_main.button?" (I'm not sure if that helps or not).

[image]

Thank you all so much for helping to get me started with Android.

EDIT

Based on feedback (THANK YOU SO MUCH BY THE WAY!!!) I clicked "ALT" and "Enter" and told the code to "import"

It brought in the line: "import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*"

Unfortunately, I still do not get the "onClickListener" option though from intellisense. I believe I have this declared as a button in the "activity_main.xml" file but maybe not? Here are my screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As you can see here, I am not getting any methods provided for me off of "button"

That is because the IDE does not recognize the `button` symbol. You have neither declared it nor imported it.

> The error I am getting is "kotlinx.android.main.activity_main.button?"

That tooltip message not an error. The red highlight of `button` is an error. The underline means "hey, we are not sure what you mean by this symbol, but we have some imports that match!". The tooltip is indicating that if you press Alt-Enter (Windows/Linux), that it will add an `import` statement for `kotlinx.android.main.activity_main.button` to your list of `import` statements at the top of the Kotlin file. If `button` is a widget in your `activity_main` layout resource, then this will work and will give you the ability to set a click listener on it.

Comment: I think I am getting closer. I used "ALT + Enter" and told it to import the line "import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*" (I'm not sure why mind has the word "synthetic" in it)

Unfortunately, I do not seem to be getting the "onClickListener" option in the dropdown. I'll try to edit my original post to show a picture.

Comment: @AdamLaurie: "I'm not sure why mind has the word "synthetic" in it" -- "Kotlin synthetic accessors" is what the JetBrains developers elected to name this capability. "Unfortunately, I do not seem to be getting the "onClickListener" option in the dropdown" -- the method you need to call is `setOnClickListener()`.

Comment: Oh wow! That last question was embarrassing. I feel like I should have found it under "setOnClickListener()" I am so sorry for not reviewing that better. Thank you so much though, you solved my problem and I'm back to programming! It's people like you that make programming enjoyable. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Here the setOnClickListener is an extension function of `Button`

In your case, the 'button' must either be an id of a button widget in activity_main.xml or a variable declared using findViewById

Answer (score 1):

This way of binding views has changed. Please take a look at this codelab:

[Use data binding to eliminate findViewById()](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-data-binding-basics/index.html#2)

In previous versions, we could directly bind a view with kotlin code. Java didn't allow that. Something has changed.